# ASP.NET Redirecting through specific mapped route depending on parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to make a login section. When you first launch the page you just go to the specified url `/Login`. When you submit and the credentials are wrong I want to redirect to the login page with the given url `/Login/Error/{errorid}`.
So the idea is whenever the errorid parameter is added to a route it should enter the Error route. Otherwise take the default route.

However I have set up the following routes but they don't seem to work. Note: I did change the Default controller a little bit.

```
routes.MapRoute("Error", "{action}/Error/{errorid}",
    new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" }
);

routes.MapRoute("Default", "{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Furthermore I have 2 controllers. My Home controller is where the landing page is aswell as the Login controller.

I also get a error when launching the application. When it goes through the redirect in the Index action it says:

> No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Session["User"] = -1;

    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
}
```

LoginController:

```
public ActionResult Login(int? errorid)
{
    if (Models.User.CheckActiveSession(Convert.ToInt32(Session["User"])))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Overview", "Home");
    }

    return View();
}

public ActionResult ValidateLogin()
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
    {
        int userid = Models.User.CheckLogin(Request.Form["username"], Request.Form["password"]);

        if (userid != -1)
        {
            Session["User"] = userid;

            return RedirectToAction("Overview", "Home");
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login", new { errorid = 1 });
}
```

I do have to say that I am new to this so I'm not sure if I'm doing this correct at all but I have read some guides on how you can do this. Any tips are appreciated. And if there are other ways you could this I would love to hear those aswell.

EDIT:

Got a small mistake within the custom route. The errorid parameter is not in the object of default parameters. If I do say that `errorid = 0` then the page does load but I see the url `/Login/Error`.

Comment: Alternatively you could code your `login/error` view to conditionally display the appropriate body for the error number.  There are many reasons why you'll be better off using as little customization of the routing tables as you can.  I don't mean to say it is wrong to use custom routes -- I just mean to say that some use cases offer chances to do something other than custom routes.  If you rely too much on custom routes you may soon find that it is difficult to maintain.

Comment: Alright thanks, but may I know why my first route in the Index page to the login page fails. Why won't it take the default route if the Error route doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your default route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Although you have specified to provide a default `controller` value of `"Home"` if no value is provided in the URL, you have not included a way to provide `{controller}` in the URL. This means there is no way to specify anything for `controller` other than `"Home"`. In other words, there is no way to get to your `LoginController` when using this default route.

There are many ways you could fix this (including going back to the original URL of `{controller}/{action}/{id}`), but it all depends on the reason why you decided to remove controller from the URL in the first place.

> Got a small mistake within the custom route. The errorid parameter is not in the object of default parameters. If I do say that errorid = 0 then the page does load but I see the url `/Login/Error`.

This is not an error. If you want to make a required value in the URL, you must not provide a default value for it. Otherwise it will be optional (meaning you can leave it off of the right side of the URL).

For it to generate a URL matching your `Error` route, you need to provide a value for `errorid` (since it is not optional).

```
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login", new { errorid = 123 });
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. However I would like to know 1 more thing. I added the {controller} back to the default route but now whenever I go to the login page I get the URL /Login/Login. This looks a bit silly, any recommendations on this?

Comment: You could insert a login route with a url value of `login` and default values of `new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" }`. Or alternatively use attribute routing. However, I would suggest using different names for controller and action (change one of them from "Login") so you don't end up confusing yourself or anyone else maintaining this code.

Comment: Alright, I just changed up the controller name to something more appropriate. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. BTW - I didn't mean you could do one or the other of the ideas - you can do both if you like. You could still add a route to make the shorter URL `login` even if the names are different. It is just confusing if the names for controller and action are the same is all I am saying.